# Comapatibility with dedicated hot water recirculation plumbing

Tags: plumbing, hot-water, pump, heat-pump

Can this Watts Premier hot water recirculating pump (0955800) be connected to a dedicated plumbing (already intalled in the house) that recirculates water back directly to the tank and does not go through the cold water line? Or does this only have to be connected to the hot water pipe out from the tank and has to use the sensor in the farthest faucet in the house for the return?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the pump here and at a Lowes store, I would have to say yes to your question. I see nothing on that pump that forces you to install it on the tanks discharge or under a sink, per instructions.

I have a re-circulation loop I installed in my home. I brought a dedicated 1/2" line from the 3 bathrooms in my home. I soldered in a "Tee" and brought all 3 dedicated lines back to the hot water tank. After each tee I added a check valve to each line to stop any back feed through that line. All 3 lines were collected into a 3/4" copper line that went to the smallest B&G pump I could find (38 watts) and connected it to the tank at the bottom drain. I added a cheap timer so the pump runs 15 minutes per hour, except at certain times when more hot water is needed for things like showers and turn it off at night.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

A hot water recirculator basically just bridges the hot and cold side of your hot water loop .Your water sources need to be a closed loop , you have to use the same water circuit that feeds the cold water line to your hot water heater, which would apply to the faucet/shower you want constant hot water.

Eg cold water input -> heater ->  hotwater output ,-> pump -> cold water input to heater.

You probably need to contact the manufacturer for their sensor equipment because they design it with particular environment to be operated in.

Things like ,
fitting thread pitch
max pressure
sustained heat load
max distance from hot water
max head pressure for a given distance of pipe
operational conditions (dual water source) ,etc

Comment: "you have to use the same water circuit that feeds the cold water line to your hot water heater..." this is not necessarily true as many recirculating systems' return line are plumbed back directly to the tank, rather than to the cold water supply line, both pumped systems and thermo-siphon systems.